# Lnurl: Why are there min and max fields instead of an amount field?

Tags: lightning-network, invoices

When creating an lnurl, why do you need to specify a range of amounts to payout using the fields `min` and `max`?

I would think it would make sense for lnurls to just take one specified amount like `amount:200` sats instead of `minWithdrawal:199` and `maxWithdrawal:200`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LNURL-PAY enables other use cases like static QR codes that can be printed and re-used many times, provides a standard for receiving sats over Lightning without having the user paste an invoice.

A common example would be a printed sign that contains a QR code for donations. The LNURL-PAY subprotocol allows the receiver to specify a range (min/max) for the accepted payment amounts. When the end-user (payer) scans the QR code, is presented with a dialog that asks how much he wants to pay. He chooses the amount, confirm the payment in his app, and then his app communicates with an LNURL server to complete the payment via the Lightning Network. In the background the protocol generates an invoice for every payment but this is transparent for the user.